# connecting google firestore to php - grpc not found

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, grpc

I am trying to connect php to firestore database following this repo https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-firestore.

Google Cloud Firestore for php requires grpc extension to be installed. I have installed grpc through pecl and it says it is perfectly installed. But whenever I try to run the code, it says firestore could not connect because grpc extension could not be found. I am attaching the screenshots of errors here. I have even added grpc to php.ini file, not sure why this error still pops up.[Proof that grpc is installed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYRSt.png) [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbybk.png)

Answer (score 0):

From php extensions check **php_grpc**, other wise it will be available for operations you do,
secondly from php.ini add 
**extension=php_grpc.dll**

Comment: this method applies inside your **wamp/bin/php/php(version 5.6--7.2)/php.ini**

Answer (score 0):

The link you've posted also features one relevant tutorial: [Install gRPC for PHP](https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc).