# google/cloud-firestore v1.17.0 requires ext-grpc

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore, composer-php

Using **free trial of Google Cloud Platform** and Following the guide:

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers#php
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/quickstart

on **Cloud Shell Terminal** it's everything OK when I run the command "php index.php" without deploy it. With the following composer.json

```
{
  "require": {
    "php": "7.2.*",
    "silex/silex": "^2.3",
    "google/cloud-firestore": "^1.17",
    "grpc/grpc": "^v1.27.0",
    "google/protobuf": "^v3.3.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "symfony/browser-kit": "^4.4",
    "symfony/http-kernel": "^4.4"
  }
}
```

But If I deploy it in order to generate a web as it's illustrated in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/quickstart with the command:

gcloud app deploy

It get the following error:

```
Step #1: Using PHP version: 7.2
Step #1: Install PHP extensions...
Step #1: Running composer...
Step #1: Loading composer repositories with package information
Step #1: Installing dependencies from lock file
Step #1: Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run
 `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`.
Step #1: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Step #1:
Step #1:   Problem 1
Step #1:     - Installation request for google/cloud-firestore v1.17.0 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-firestore[v1.17.0].
Step #1:     - google/cloud-firestore v1.17.0 requires ext-grpc * -> the requested PHP extension grpc is missing from your system.
Step #1:
Step #1:   To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
Step #1:     - /opt/php72/lib/php-cli.ini
Step #1:     - /opt/php72/lib/ext.enabled/ext-apcu-bc.ini
Step #1:     - /opt/php72/lib/ext.enabled/ext-mailparse.ini
Step #1:     - /opt/php72/lib/ext.enabled/ext-memcached.ini
Step #1:   You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Step #1: error building image: error building stage: waiting for process to exit: exit status 2
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor@sha256:f87c11770a4d3ed33436508d206c584812cd656e6ed08eda1cff5c1ee44f5870" failed: step exited with non-zero statu
s: 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cloud build failed. Check logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/0cc3bd85-9138-4273-a59e-86daf2065051?project=981117
417638 Failure status: UNKNOWN: Error Response: [2] Build failed; check build logs for details
```

And of course I added in /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini the line extension=grpc.so. I executed the command  php --ini in order to find all files.
I know that this question seems to be repeated but it has not resolved for this case yet.

Comment: There are improvements with each version of Google Cloud SDK. Please run the command: "gcloud components update" then try to deploy the application again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541066/connecting-google-firestore-to-php-grpc-not-found/57509391